# Pure rolling and friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

If I launch a rigid cylinder (or sphere, etc.) to the surface which has a coefficient of kinetic friction $\mu_k$ and static friction $\mu_s$ with some initial velocity $v$ I think it will decelerate and rotate (with slipping) because of kinetic friction. If after sometime, it reaches to the state of pure rolling, Does the kinetic friction changes to static friction? If it's true, does the pure rolling continue? I understand that static friction makes torque. But does it retard the translational motion of body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting thing is that once the pure rolling condition $v=\omega R$ is reached there is **no** frictional force acting on the cylinder.
So the cylinder rolls along with a constant translational velocity (no net force) and a constant rotational velocity (no net torque).